# Exact functors and their naive universal $\delta$-functors

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

This is Exercise 2.1.2 of Weibel's Introduction to homological algebra, and it might actually be a very simple exercise.

For $F: \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ an exact functor, I want to show that $T_0 = F$ and $T_n = 0$ for $n \neq 0$ defines a universal $\delta$-functor.

Since $F$ is exact, then $T$ is almost trivially a $\delta$-functor, since the boundary maps are zero.

Then to check universality, if $S : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ is another $\delta$-functor for which there is a natural transformation of $S_0$ to $T_0 = F$, and $S_n$ to $T_n = 0$ for $n \neq 0$, then surely this is unique almost by construction? I am not sure if there is some nuance or detail to the argument that I am missing here, as I am not super familiar with homological algebra arguments in full generality.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be a triviality.

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial but worth expanding on. As you say, the boundary map $T_1(C)\to T_0(A)$ is trivial because $F=T_0$ is left exact. Now for any other $\delta$ functor $S_*$ you can define $S_n\to T_n=0$ to be the trivial natural transformation whenever $n>0$ (this is the only possible nat. trans. into the trivial functor!). You just need to see that when applied to a short exact sequence this gives a map between the long exact sequences for $S_*$ and $T_*$.

I think getting used to working with commutative diagrams is something that this exercise will help with if you write it out in full.